# mainView.router.loadPage not working in ajax success

Tags: html-framework-7

Is it possible to redirect searchusers.html with this coding?

```
myApp.onPageInit('home', function (page) {
$$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://localhost/some.php?name="+window.localStorage.getItem('key'),
    cache : false,
    async: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success:function(data){ 
        if (data == "nooneinfollowinglist") {
            mainView.router.loadPage('searchusers.html');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not possible to redirect this way. Using event only we can redirect page like this:

```
myApp.alert('nobody',function(){
    mainView.router.loadPage('searchusers.html');
});
```